# Efficient method of changing the image displayed on an <img>?

Tags: javascript, html, image

In javascript, I have a reference to a DOM `<img>` element. I need to change the image displayed by the `<img>` from within the javascript.

So far, I have tried this by changing the `image.src` attribute to the URL of the new image. This worked, but there is still a problem: I need the image to be changed many times per second, and changing the `src` attribute causes the browser to do a new GET request for the image (which is already cached), which puts strain on the web server since there will be hundreds of simultanious clients.

My current (inefficient) solution is done like this:

```js
let image = document.querySelector("img");

setInterval(function(){
    image.src = getNextImageURL();//this causes a GET request
}, 10);

function getNextImageURL() {
   /*...implementation...*/
}
```

```html
<img>
```

I am looking for a more efficient way of changing the image, that does not cause any unnecessary HTTP requests.

Comment: render all the images you need, and hide them, then show the one you want. That's the only way you're gonna be able to do this without needing more HTTP requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sprite-sheet idea doesn't work (e.g because you have big images), then use a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/).

You just need to preload all your images, store them in an Array and then draw them one after the other on your canvas:

```js
const urls = new Array(35).fill(0).map((v, i) =>
  'https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=' + i
 );
// load all the images
const loadImg = Promise.all(
  urls.map(url => 
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // each url will have its own <img>
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = e => res(img);
      img.onerror = rej;
      img.src = url;
    })
  )
);
// when they're all loaded
loadImg.then(imgs => {
  // prepare the canvas
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  // set its size
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;
  // get the drawing context
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let i = 0;
  // start the animation
  anim();

  function anim() {
    // do it again at next screen refresh (~16ms on a 60Hz monitor)
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    // increment our index
    i = (i + 1) % imgs.length;
    // draw the required image
    ctx.drawImage(imgs[i], 0, 0);
  }
})
.catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And if you wish time control:

```js
const urls = new Array(35).fill(0).map((v, i) =>
  'https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=' + i
 );
// load all the images
const loadImg = Promise.all(
  urls.map(url => 
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // each url will have its own <img>
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = e => res(img);
      img.onerror = rej;
      img.src = url;
    })
  )
);
// when they're all loaded
loadImg.then(imgs => {
  // prepare the canvas
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  // set its size
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;
  // get the drawing context
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const duration = 100; // the number of ms each image should last
  let i = 0;
  let lastTime = performance.now();

  // start the animation
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);

  // rAF passes a timestamp
  function anim(time) {
    // do it again at next screen refresh (~16ms on a 60Hz monitor)
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);

    const timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    if(timeDiff < duration) { // duration has not yet elapsed
      return;
    }
    // update lastTime
    lastTime = time - (timeDiff - duration);
    // increment our index
    i = (i + 1) % (imgs.length);
    // draw the required image
    ctx.drawImage(imgs[i], 0, 0);
  }
})
.catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this may be what I need to do. I was hoping there would be an easier way, but I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to code in a different way...

if you want to reduce requests you should combine all image in one sprite Sheet.
this trick is used so many in-game animations.
But you will need to change `<img/>` tag to another tag like `<div></div>`

the idea here is that we have one image and we just change the viewport for what we want

**sample For sprite sheet**

[image]

```js
let element = document.querySelector("div");
let i = 1
setInterval(function(){
    element.style.backgroundPosition= getNextImagePostion(i++);//this will change the posion
}, 100);

function getNextImagePostion(nextPos) {
   /*...implementation...*/

   // this just for try
   //  6 is the number of images in sheet
   // 20 is the height for one segment in sheet
   var posX = 100*(nextPos%6);

  // first is position on x and latter is position on y
   return "-"+posX+"px 0px ";
}
```

```css
.image {
    width: 100px; /*  width of single image*/
    height: 100px; /*height of single image*/
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/500/100?image=8) /*path to your sprite sheet*/
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, however, you cannot do this with too big images, it would then be too heavy...

Comment: I think its the best solution for this case , he wants to  make animation